# Is there way to tweak the headphones/mic combo jack to accept only input?

Tags: audio, microphone, headphones, headset

I have a laptop with 2 jacks: 1 is a headphones jack, and the other is a headphones/mic combo jack. Both 3.5mm.

However, I have a headset that comes with 2 plugs, a mic and a headphones plug.

So, I was wondering if there was a way I could simply just plug the headphones plug in the headphones jack, tweak the combo jack, and plug the mic into the combo jack.

Okay, seems that there's some confusion.

I meant, can I use the combo jack as a mic jack? I figured out that I can't, and I was wondering if anyone new a way to make this happen, be it a driver tweak, or something like that. Thanks

Comment: That would be up to the OS and software, and of course the specific hardware.

Comment: From your description, it seems as if you just insert the headphone jack to the headphone female on the laptop and the mic to the combo jack there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: The Headset is SteelSeries Siberia V2, and the laptop is an HP ENVY 14t-1000.

Windows 7 Ultimate, eh, that's about as much as I can say right now.